# Axis2: Create a Two Service class from one WSDL file onl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have this one WSDL file with two different methods, "get" and "set". It has one Service class called BasicOperationService implemented from java2wsdl command. We have observed that "get" and "set" methods has really different dependencies. Thats why we are thinking to create GetOperationService and SetOperationService with one MessageReceiverInOut. Is this approach possible and if ever I need some coaching on how to use axis2. Thanks